# Согласие пользователя из ЕС на предоставление личных данных

Tags: android

Есть платное приложение на google play без рекламы, нужно ли согласие пользователей из ЕС на предоставление личных данных в google для аналитики которые он использует для статистики?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, нужно, т.к. аналитика для отличения юзеров использует данные, которые считаются личными по этому закону и, следовательно, требуется согласие юзеров.